# How to escape this selector make it working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, escaping

I have a radio

```
<input type="radio" name="<_WallForm>" value="=(1,2,3)">
```

with the script

```
n = n.replace('<', '\\<').replace('>', '\\>').replace('=', '\\=');
v = v.replace('<', '\\<').replace('>', '\\>').replace('=', '\\=');

f.find('input[type=radio][name=' + n + '][value=' + v +']').parent().parent().find('.selectPic').click();
```

the error

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=radio][name=\<_WallForm\>][value=\=(1,2,3)]`

so how to do?
thank you.

Comment: Just put the attribute values inside quotes. No escape necessary (only quotes that you use, if there is a change the names could contain them).

Comment: I would avoid using angle brackets for the names of elements in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to escape anything. Just add quotes to your attribute selectors (and get rid of the first couple of lines):

```
f.find('input[type="radio"][name="' + n + '"][value="' + v +'"]').parent().parent().find('.selectPic').click();
```

This should result in a selector like

```
input[type="radio"][name="<_WallForm>"][value="=(1,2,3)"]
```

... which you will notice is similar to how your attribute values are quoted in your HTML.

---

On a side note, you *will* need to encode your angle brackets in order for your HTML to validate:

```
<input type="radio" name="&lt;_WallForm&gt;" value="=(1,2,3)">
```

But you do not have to reflect this in your selector — in fact, if you try to do that the selector may stop matching, because HTML entity references are not recognized in selectors; they'll just be taken literally.

As mentioned in the comments, your life will be easier if you avoid using special characters like angle brackets and the `&` sign in arbitrary values where possible.

Answer (score 0):

your single quotes are colliding with each other. Try changing your statement to this...

```
f.find('input[type="radio"][name="' + n + '"][value="' + v + '"]').parent().parent().find('.selectPic').click();
```